# Is there a way to have a ioctl() with new(customized) command

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, systems-programming, nvme

I am working on a testing tool for nvme-cli(written in c and can run on linux).

For SSD validation purpose, i was actually looking for a custom command(For e.g. I/O command, write and then read the same and finally compare if both the data are same)

In user space i need to invoke minimum of 2 `ioclt()` one with write command(nvme_cmd_write) and another with read command(nvme_cmd_read) and compare both the buffer contents.

Issue is actually when i wanted to send this command in parallel. At block level (using `ioclt()`)we were not able to put this command in different I/O submission queues.

so can we have a custom command (nvme_cmd_write_compare) sent from `ioclt()` and have a new module at driver level for handling this new command.

Since I am new to this nvme/ioctl(), if there is any mistakes please correct me.

I wanted to know if we can implement this.

Comment: Can you post the code what have you done so far? You can definitely write your custom IOCTL, for this you need to edit the driver code.

Comment: @Gaurav https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646051/can-i-invoke-ioctl-system-call-for-nvme-with-different-threads-using-pthread?noredirect=1#comment82253428_47646051

Comment: @Gaurav for editing the driver code, can i refer anything? Any resources for writing custom IOCTL will be helpful

Comment: The link to the code that you provided is for user-space program. Can you please post the driver code?

Comment: You can just google it and you will get plenty of results. Search for "custom IOCTL".